# Print a specific digit in a number in Python

Tags: python

How do I print a specific part of a number in Python? 
For example, only print the last 10 digits of a .

```
a = 5672839
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? what's your expected out put and what's wrong with your result?here the length of `a` is 7 so, how you want to get the last 10 digit?

Comment: @Andy in the title yes, but in the body, no.